# Get count per year of data with begin and end dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, union

I have a set of data that lists each employee ever employed in a certain type of department at many cities, and it lists each employee's begin and end date.

For example:

```
name        city_id  start_date  end_date
-----------------------------------------
Joe Public  54       3-19-1994   9-1-2002
Suzi Que    54       10-1-1995   9-1-2005
```

What I want is each city's employee count for each year in a particular period. For example, if this was all the data for city 54, then I'd show this as the query results if I wanted to show city 54's employee count for the years 1990-2005:

```
city_id  year  employee_count
-----------------------------
54       1990  0
54       1991  0
54       1992  0
54       1993  0
54       1994  1
54       1995  2
54       1996  2
54       1997  2
54       1998  2
54       1999  2
54       2000  2
54       2001  2
54       2002  2
54       2003  1
54       2004  1
54       2005  1
```

(Note that I will have many cities, so the primary key here would be city and year unless I want to have a separate id column.)

Is there an efficient SQL query to do this? All I can think of is a series of UNIONed queries, with one query for each year I wanted to get numbers for.

My dataset has a few hundred cities and 178,000 employee records. I need to find a few decades' worth of this yearly data for each city on my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `54` with your parameter

```
select
    <city_id>, c.y, count(t.city_id)
from generate_series(1990, 2005) as c(y)
    left outer join Table1 as t on
          c.y between extract(year from t.start_date) and extract(year from t.end_date) and
          t.city_id = <city_id>
group by c.y
order by c.y
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3e9a6/14)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of `generate_series`. One note is that the query could be shorter with `count(*)` and produce the same result. I also modified to count all my cities by adding the city id to the `GROUP BY` clause, removing `and t.city_id = <city_id>`, and replacing your placeholder `<city_id>` with `t.city_id` in the SELECTed columns.